# SQL insert both specified and selected values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, insert, sybase

I have two tables shown below:
TableOwner:

```
UserID    Name      Initials  
1         Peter     Pet1  
2         Mary      Mar1
3         Petra     Pet2
```

TableAsset

```
AssetID   AssetName    OwnerUserID  
1         Samsung      3  
2         Apple        1  
3         Huawei       2
```

Now I want to insert into TableAsset these records:

```
AssetID   AssetName   OwnerUserID  
4         Doro        2
5         Sony        1
```

How to use `insert` query and `select` query in one step?

Comment: mysql & sql-server, sybase refers different choose any one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in a single query. Passing the parameter will depend on you how you do it.

```
insert into TableAsset(AssetName, OwnerUserID)
select 'Doro', (select UserID from TableOwner where Initials = 'Mar1')
union all
select 'Sony', (select UserID from TableOwner where Initials = 'Pet1');
```

Comment: So easy, so simple.

Answer (score -1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You can look them up:

```
insert into tableAsset(AssetName, OwnerUserID)
    select @AssetName, o.UserId
    from tableOwner o
    where o.initials = @Initials;
```

This basic structure will work for any database, although the method for passing parameters may differ among databases.